# While adding two numbers getting NAN as output in the react?

Tags: reactjs, nan, parseint, parsefloat

When I am trying to add two numbers, I am able to get NaN. If anyone has any advice, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my Code:-

```
  var sum = parseInt(label.labellength, 10) + parseInt(label.labely, 10);
  console.log("Sum of FrontRight is " + sum );
```

Output is:-NaN

I tried as following :

Using Number

```
  var sum=Number(label.labellength) + Number(label.labely);
```

Output is:-NaN

Comment: what is label, where is it coming from?

Comment: Check the values of label.labellength and label.labely. They both might not be numbers.

Comment: Can you add the following statement print content of these variables?

 `console.log(label.labellength, parseInt(label.labely)`

Comment: label is a function

Comment: Please add full code or codesandbox link.

Comment: @TheKNVB When I trying this console.log(label.labellength, parseInt(label.labely) 
The Cube is Out in the web.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue came to me , try to use `||` operator and return it, it did the same and it worked for me...

```
const [contextOverHr,setContextOverHr=useState("")
return (
  {Object.values(workHour).reduce((pre,total) => {
                  let totalNum = pre + total.OverHour
                  setContextOverHr (totalNum)
                  return totalNum || 0
                },0)
  }
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).